# Making a Java Application dynamic

Tags: java, mysql, swing, phpmyadmin

I have created a Java Application (Hardware Inventory Management System) in NetBeans 8.0.2 and it is working perfectly. It currently has 8 tables namely Desktops, Laptops etc. But these tables were created by me in PhpMyAdmin. Also the UI containing the panels, tables and radio buttons were put in by me in the JFrame form.

Presently this is fine but if I want to add new hardware in the future (eg. Printers) How do I add that functionality? I want my application to be able to create new tables and create the corresponding CRUD Tables, links from menus etc. How do I do that?

Comment: Those are products/concepts; so it's more likely have the wrong model (`DESKTOPS`, `LAPTOPS`, etc) for representing `DEVICES`

Comment: Its an inventory for the desktops, laptops, servers etc that a company owns. The CRUD tables show which users have been allotted which laptops (which are distinguished using unique asset codes given to all hardware items). The model is correct. I just need a way to expand it dynamically.

Comment: Well, then the company has the wrong model...rest assured. You must abstract the representation of that "something" you want to store/model...just think about it: how many tables you would have if you have `N` devices? Worst, how many CRUD classes?

Comment: What do you suggest I do in order to remedy the situation?

Comment: I would model the database in the "normal" way and use rows to represent your "devices"; you shouldn't allow anyone to create tables on the fly. Can you update your question and post the schema for those tables...or at least two of them?

Answer (score 0):

Make a special interface for adding new Hardware : **ADD Hardware interface**.

- In this create a form in which take the details of new Hardware to be included (Printer say for example).
- Connect to Database and Run Create table query and corresponding CRUD table queries and insert the required details in Printer table.

Hope it helps.